# minimum bounding rectangle c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge, accord.net

I have a list of points depicting a shape. In C# need to find the Minimum Bounding Rectangle (MBR) for that shape. However, all the solutions I have been able to find result in a MBR that is relative to the x and y axis, not to the shape itself.
As an example, (the shape is not fixed, could be anything);

[image: MBR auto-generated]

What I would really like is something like this;

[image: MBR manually drawn]

Currently I am using the getBoundingRectangle in accord.net. The only thing I can think of would be to try 1->90 degree rotations, until the size of the bounding rectangle was minimized.

EDIT:
I have found a good reference for the problem here;

[Best fit rectangles](http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/march12014/index.html)

It has the code for the solution in processing.js here (see GenBox);

[Solution in processing.js](http://view-source:http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/march12014/TestLines.pde)
But I would really like a C# solution

Comment: I don't know C# so I can't answer this but a common way is to find the angle of rotation of the shape, undo the rotation so that the shape is horizontal, use the logic to find the MBR with respect to the x and y axis, then redo the rotation on that shape to achieve the final answer.  Have a look at this post to determine how to find the angle that a rectangular shape makes if you know the four corners.  This is probably adaptable to the shape you have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002979/how-to-calculate-rotation-angle-from-rectangle-points

Comment: This is a non-trivial topic.  I found some algorithms for calculating it here https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MinimumAreaRectangle.pdf

Comment: @rayryeng thanks, though I don't really have 4 corners, even the shape showing is just an example. I'll edit to make that clearer

Comment: @BradleyUffner Nice link. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @BradleyUffner good link, at least it might be handy as a reference