# Finding the midpoint of the rotated rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, math, geometry, coordinates

I would like to find the midpoint of a rotated rectangle.  The rotated rectangle has got the following coordinate

> [[317, 80], [183, 291], [479, 150], [378, 387]]

I have got the following code to determine

```
cx = (coord[0][0] + coord[2][0])//2
cy = (coord[0][1] + coord[1][1])//2
```

Unfortunately, the center doesn't correspond to the actual center. How do I find the exact center of the above coordinates?

Comment: You mean the centroid of the rectangle?

Comment: yes the centroid of the rectangle while it is rotated.

Comment: Do you have a sample image?

Comment: `coord[1][1]` did you mean `coord[2][1]`, you are trying to find the midpoint of the diagonal from `coord[0]` to `coord[2]`. So using `coord[1]` in the second calculation is wrong. And using `//` will force it to an integer even if goes to a `0.5` point.

Comment: The values returned from the rotated rectangle should be the ((centroid x,y), (width, height), (color)). You must be converting the rotated rectangle into its box 4 corners, which you do not need to do if you only want the centroid coordinates. See the rotated rect structure at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/db/dd6/classcv_1_1RotatedRect.html#ae1be388780b8d5faf450be18cbbf30f1

Comment: At the moment the title doesn't match the contents of the question.

I suggest to either change in the title the word 'rectangle' to 'quadrangle' or to give an example of coordinates, that really represent a rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure if I’m following you, man, but if you want to calculate the centroid of a rectangle shape, it goes like this. Suppose you have the following rectangle aligned to the origin. The centroid is shown in green.

[image]

The centroid is computed as:

```
Cx = 0.5 * w
Cy = 0.5 * h
```

You can then apply a linear transformation. In this example, a rotation matrix, which is given as:

```
R = [ cos ϴ, -sin ϴ
      sin ϴ,  cos ϴ ]
```

The rectangle is now rotated from the original coordinate system. That’s the angle ϴ:

[image]

The centroid equations become:

```
Cx’ = cx cos ϴ - cy sin ϴ
Cy’ = cx sin ϴ + cy cos ϴ
```

Translating back to the coordinate original system, we’ve got:

```
Cx’’ = x + cx cos ϴ - cy sin ϴ
Cy’’ = y + cx sin ϴ + cy cos ϴ
```

The function should be something like this (in pseudo-code):

```
Tuple computeRotatedCentroid( x, y, width, height, theta ) {
    cx = 0.5 * width;
    cy = 0.5 * height;

    thetaRadians = degreesToRadians(theta);

    cosTheta = cos( thetaRadians );
    sinTheta = sin( thetaRadians );

    finalCx = x + cx * cosTheta - cy * sinTheta;
    finalCy = y + cx * sinTheta + cy * cosTheta;

    return makeTuple( finalCx, finalCy );
}
```

Comment: thank you! May I know the value that I must pass onto theta argument?

Comment: No problem, my friend! Theta is the rotation angle (in degrees).

Comment: Could you please point me a formula to find the angle for the 4 coordinate system? :)

Comment: Mmhh, Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002979/how-to-calculate-rotation-angle-from-rectangle-points

Answer (score 2):

The centroid of a rectangle is the midpoint of either diagonal.  You used different point pairs for your two coordinate computations.  Also note that, for some reason, the points are *not* in the usual, adjacent order.  The diagonals are points 1 & 2, 0 & 3.  Use either pair, such as:

```
# Variables to make the computations easier to read
pt1 = 1
pt2 = 2
x = 0
y = 1
cx = (coord[pt1][x] + coord[pt2][x])//2
cy = (coord[pt1][y] + coord[pt2][y])//2
```

Better yet, research some simple shape modules.  Most of these will have a straightforward `midpoint` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the midpoint of a rotated rectangle (the centroid) with [`cv2.minAreaRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect). The function returns the following information:

```
(centroid, (width, height), angle) = cv2.minAreaRect(cnts)
```

Here's a simple example. Input image:

[image]

Result with the centroid highlighted in green

[image]

Coordinates

```
(157.6988067626953, 132.07565307617188)
```

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and find centroid information on rotated rectangle
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
centroid, dimensions, angle = cv2.minAreaRect(cnts[0])
cv2.circle(image, (int(centroid[0]), int(centroid[1])), 5, (36,255,12), -1)

print(centroid)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues.

1.) The points are not ordered correctly for your formula to work. I guess they should be ordered like: (points should be ordered such, that you have a line of the rectangle between two points that are adjacent in the list and the last and first entry in the list)

```
points = [[183, 291], [378, 387], [479, 150], [317, 80]]
```

2.) There is a mistake in your formula. (I guess the formula should be the one, that finds the mid point of a line or in this case the midpoint of a diagonal between point 0 and point 2).

It should be

```
cx = (coord[idx1][0] + coord[idx2][0]) / 2
cy = (coord[idx1][1] + coord[idx2][1]) / 2

where idx1, idx2 are either 0,2 or 1,3
```

For a rectangle cx, cy will be identical regardless of whether you use idx1=0, idx2=2 or idx1=1, idx2=3

3.) This formula (midpoint of a diagonal) determines the centroid only for rectangles. What you have is a quadrangle, which is almost, but not exactly a rectangle, so the formula does not apply at all.

Try to calculate cx, cy with idx1, idx2 = 0, 2 and with idx1, idx2 = 1, 3
and you see, that you get different results. Thus you do not have a rectangle.

Either there is a typo in the coordinates, that you posted, or perhaps there is an error in the formula that calculated your rectangle or your question really meant to calculate the centroid of a quadrangle, which is different. 
In that case it might be advisable to adapt the title of the question

You can find the formula for a polygon here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_polygon

Comment: confirmed, that what you have is not a rectangle and adapted my answer accordingly

and clarified response slightly

Comment: tries once more to clarify and point out, that it would be a good idea to 'fix' the question. in the moment the title and the pixel coordinates contradict each other.